# httpclient5 with connection pooling in java

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am trying to use httpclient5 with connection pooling. Below are some of the points mentioned in documentation:

> `CloseableHttpClient` instances should be closed when no longer needed
> or about to go out of score.
>
> IMPORTANT: Always re-use `CloseableHttpClient` instances. They are
> expensive to create, but they are also fully thread safe, so multiple
> threads can use the same instance of `CloseableHttpClient` to execute
> multiple requests concurrently taking full advantage of persistent
> connection re-use and connection pooling.

I feel both of them feels contradictory. How should I proceed with this?
Also in case if I am reusing `CloseableHttpClient` instances how can I change credentials for different requests which uses same client?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Your last question is a separate concern and should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: This is not clear question. Why do you think the documentation is contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

the points are not contradicting, creating a new instance of `CloseableHttpClient` is expensive, but it is also fully thread-safe, so multiple threads can use the same instance of `CloseableHttpClient` to execute multiple requests concurrently.

To change credentials for different requests that use the same client, you can use the `CredentialsProvider` class to manage your credentials.

```py
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

# Create a credentials provider and set the credentials for a specific AuthScope
creds_provider = BasicCredentialsProvider()
creds_provider.set_credentials(AuthScope("localhost", 8080), UsernamePasswordCredentials("user1", "password1"))

# Create an HttpClientBuilder and set the credentials provider
http_client_builder = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(creds_provider)

# Build the CloseableHttpClient instance
http_client = http_client_builder.build()

# Use the CloseableHttpClient instance to execute your requests
response1 = http_client.execute(request1)
response2 = http_client.execute(request2)

# Set different credentials for a different AuthScope
creds_provider.set_credentials(AuthScope("localhost", 8081), UsernamePasswordCredentials("user2", "password2"))

# Use the same CloseableHttpClient instance to execute another request with different credentials
response3 = http_client.execute(request3)
```

Comment: This does not look thread-safe at all just swapping out credentials on the fly that allegedly are being used by a client that is used by multiple threads at the same time. I say allegedly because I'm not going to dig into how the builder distributes that credentials provider to the clients it builds.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your auth type... for e.g. basic auth just set the header manually for each request

```
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION);
final String auth = DEFAULT_USER + ":" + DEFAULT_PASS;
final byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
final String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
```

https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-basic-authentication